# mex linker not finding mexFunction symbol

Tags: matlab, linker, mex

Up until recently I've been able to compile mex functions fine on my mac osx 10.8.4
but now it gives me the error as follows (for convenience I have included the entire -v invocation):

```
**************************************************************************
Warning: Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected. 
Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require
the use of -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims
option. For more information, see:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-    
api.html
**************************************************************************

-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = .)
 FILE = /Users/munanxu/Dropbox/Code/CUDA/mexThomasTDM/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app
->    CC                    = xcrun  -sdk macosx10.7  clang
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -fno-common -arch x86_64 -isysroot   
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOS
X10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7  -fexceptions
     CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
     COPTIMFLAGS        = -O2 -DNDEBUG
     CLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat - 
     lstdc++
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = xcrun  -sdk macosx10.7  clang++
->    CXX flags:
      CXXFLAGS           = -fno-common -fexceptions -arch x86_64 -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX
10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
     CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
     CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O2 -DNDEBUG
     CXXLIBS            = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -
lstdc++
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
     FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -m64 -fbackslash
     FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
     FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
     FLIBS              = -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -L    
-lgfortran -L -lgfortranbegin
     arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = xcrun -sdk macosx10.7 clang
->    Link flags:
     LDFLAGS            = -arch x86_64 -Wl,-        
syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -bundle -Wl,-  
exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map
     LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
     LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
     LDEXTENSION        = .mexmaci64
     arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
     LDCXXFLAGS         = 
     LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
     LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
     LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
     arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------

-> xcrun -sdk macosx10.7 clang -g -arch x86_64 -Wl,-  

syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -bundle -Wl,-
exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  
"inputsTest.mexmaci64"   "inputsTest.o"  -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx 
-lmex -lmat -lstdc++

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_mexFunction", referenced from:
     -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I had copied the original mexopts.sh file to the local directory to ensure that the mex compiler was using the correct version. I had also previously compiled my cpp file using g++ just to make sure the code was compiled natively for the x86_64 architecture. However, the same result occurs when I attempt to use the mex compiler to do compilation and linking. 
Any ideas on what might be going on here? It seems that people have had this issue before, but mostly with missing libraries or definitions. I have definitely defined a mexFunction in my source file.

Comment: Also, this is not unique to this specific file, and seems to only affect my osx machine. I've tried many different otherwise correct source files to find the same error, and I can compile fine on windows.

Comment: how about running `mex -setup` again to recreate `mexopts.sh` file, and delete any local versions. I don't own a Mac so I dont know if this matters, but make sure you have a compatible compiler for your system: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/index.html?sec=maci64

Answer (score 0):

I think Amro is correct, I would put this as a comment, but it's a bit large, I find this for [clang command line options to select target CPU](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-March/020135.html)

> ```
> Registered Targets:
>  alpha    - Alpha [experimental]
>  arm      - ARM
>  bfin     - Analog Devices Blackfin [experimental]
>  c        - C backend ... ...
>  mblaze   - MBlaze
>  mips     - Mips ...
>  msp430   - MSP430 [experimental] ...
>  thumb    - Thumb
>  x86      - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
>  x86-64   - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
>  xcore    - XCoreI'm thinking Amro is correct:
> ```

So is `-arch x86-64` the right command line switch, rather than `x86_64`

Comment: should be. I'm running xcode 4.6, and my cpu is a sandy bridge i7.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, `x86-64` instead of `x86_64`

Comment: normally you shouldnt have to edit these things manually, `mex -setup` is supposed to figure out the correct flags (assuming you selected a supported compiler). The question is whether `clang` is supported or does it require `gcc` instead? I've heard that Xcode now comes with clang by default..